# Vue.js вывод сообщения при не найденных данных

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Вопрос такой, есть цикл при котором мы выводим все что нашли в массиве.

```
 <v-text-field v-model="epgFilter"></v-text-field> //инпут ввода

<div 
v-if="~program.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(epgFilter.toLowerCase()) || ~program.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(epgFilter.toLowerCase()) || ~program.date.startTime.toLowerCase().indexOf(epgFilter.toLowerCase())"
 v-for="program in filteredPrograms">


data () {
            return {
                channelsFilter: '',
                epgFilter:'',

            }
        },
    computed: {
                filteredPrograms() {
                    if(this.currentPrograms) {
                        return this.currentPrograms.filter(program => {
                            if(this.selectedProgramDay == program.date.day) {
                                return program;
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            },
```

Какой написать для него `v-else` в котором будет сообщение что по запросу ничего не найдено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой же `v-else` должен подойти:

```
<div 
v-if="~program.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(epgFilter.toLowerCase()) || ~program.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(epgFilter.toLowerCase()) || ~program.date.startTime.toLowerCase().indexOf(epgFilter.toLowerCase())"
 v-for="program in filteredPrograms">
<div v-else>
  Ничего не найдено.
</div>
```

Или вынести `v-if` в отдельный блок:

```
<div 
v-if="~program.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(epgFilter.toLowerCase()) || ~program.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(epgFilter.toLowerCase()) || ~program.date.startTime.toLowerCase().indexOf(epgFilter.toLowerCase())">
    <div v-for="program in filteredPrograms"></div>
</div>
<div v-else>
  Ничего не найдено.
</div>
```

И так же советую такие условия выносить в `computed` или `methods`, зачем же вы тогда `Vue` юзаете в таком случае.

Comment: Если вынести в отдельный блок, не работает.
Простой `v-else` выводите "Ничего не найдено" для каждого элемента.
Допустим у нас 50 `program `, он и выведет 50 "Ничего не найдено" .